# How do I get slug of term by his name?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, slug

The WC_Order_Item_Meta::get_formatted() function returns terms array of the order.
Each term is an array of three things:

```
'key'   => $meta->key // attribute key
'label' => wc_attribute_label( $attribute_key, $this->product ) // attribute label
'value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value', $meta->value ) // term value
```

Also I need term slug, how do I can get the slug of the term if I know attribute key/attribute label/term value??

Answer (score 0):

This is the output of the function:

```
array(
        'pa_size' => array(
          'label' => 'Size',
          'value' => 'Medium',
        )
     )
```

You get the slug like this:

```
$terms =  WC_Order_Item_Meta::get_formatted();
foreach($terms as $slug => $term){

}
```

Comment: No, label is not a slug of the term, it is slug of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found solution:

```
$slug = '';
$item_ = $this->item['item_meta'];
foreach ($item_ as $meta_ => $term_)
{
    if(substr($meta_,0,3) == 'pa_' && $meta_ == $meta->key)
    {
        $slug = $term_[0];
        break;
    }
}

$formatted_meta[ $meta_id ] = array(
    'key'   => $meta->key,
    'label' => wc_attribute_label( $attribute_key, $this->product ),
    'value' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value', $meta->value ),
    'slug'  => $slug,
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$term = get_term_by( '1', '2', '3' );
```

1. Replace with what you are trying to retrieve by so 'name' or 'slug' or 'ID'
2. Your term label
3. The taxonomy so if you wanted to search by post category you would put 'category'

Comment: What I write instead of 'name' and 'taxonomytype'?

Comment: Sorry trying to do this from a mobile let me amend to make more clear

Comment: I tried to add `'slug' => get_term_by( 'slug', wc_attribute_label( $attribute_key, $this->product), $meta->key )` but it does not return anything.